# Cross-sectional dependence in longitudinal survey data

Tags: panel-data, survey, independence

I am using data from a longitudinal survey, where the sampling unit is **the household**. Once households are selected, data is collected from each eligible individual in the household.

My model is defined at **the individual** level. Since several members from a households are in my model, **does my model suffer from cross-sectional dependence (CSD)?**

At first I thought this was a trivial matter, and that it was obvious that my model suffers from CSD. But then looking at [survey papers](https://www.dallasfed.org/assets/documents/institute/wpapers/2013/0153.pdf), CSD seems to arise due to omitted common effects, spatial effects, common shocks, but not a single mention on sampling.

Exploring further, I can see that common effects refers to some factors affecting **all individuals** (e.g. oil shock). In my case, my concern is with common effects **within households** (e.g. same neighborhood). **Is then CSD not a problem because the size of the household is insignificant in a large dataset?** Thus, $E(e_{it}e_{jt}) \approx 0, \quad \forall i\neq j $?

I am surprised how little the literature in my field worries about CSD. Is this because it is an ubiquitous issue with every (longitudinal) survey dataset? (a bit like measurement errors... hardly anyone account for them). The following is a quote from Wooldridge (2010), p.6:

> For better or worse, spatial correlation is often ignored in applied work because correcting the problem can be difficult.

Comment: I think the reason measurement error isn't modeled explicitly is that in most cases there's no way to distinguish it from the rest of the unit-level unaccountable variability.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what "cross-sectional dependence" means, but I assume it means dependence between subjects, as opposed to the dependence between timepoints that you naturally expect in a longitudinal setting. In that case, I agree with you: sampling subjects who are grouped into households means that there is dependence between subjects in the same household. (E.g., knowing a father's height tells you something about his son's height.) A good way to deal with this in a mixed-model context is to have a per-household random effect. It might be that accounting for this dependency won't meaningfully change the conclusions of your analysis, and so it can be safely ignored—but there's no real way to tell in advance, so it makes more sense not to ignore it.

Comment: @luchonacho "**Not** to ignore it", since you can't tell in advance whether it will be important.